# Cannot save image in the png format

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, http-headers

When I type a url of a image on browser, it will show the image preview.
I right click my mouse and choose 'save image as' item, it will show a file save dialog like this:

[image]

As the picture shows, the Format option cannot choose, it only have the 'All Files' option。**how can i choose png or jpeg option ?**

I view the image network by chrome dev, it shows:

[image]

how can i solve it, anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

just add the img url **.png** Extension and save.

Comment: But the images are stored on CDN, at now I cannot add png or jpeg extension

Answer (score 0):

It is my mistake, I should value the filename with .jpeg or .jpg extension in the Content-Disposition.
And this question should be closed, but I don't how to close. Hope I did not disturb you